# How can I update state in Component A from Component B?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, jsx

Below code is some code that exist in our home-page, which has a state variable called: *cityCountry*, **that I try to parse to the component EuropeMap, so that I can update the cityCountry in the Home component from the EuropeMap component.**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import EuropeMap from "../components/EuropeMap";
//Styling
import "../css/index.css";
import "../css/grid.css";
import "../css/normalize.css";
//Components
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import Search from "../components/SearchByCity";
import FetchClass from "../components/FetchClass";
import WeatherBox from "../components/WeatherBox";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      weatherBoxId: "",
      weatherBox: false,
      city: this.props.city,
      cityCountry: [],
      weather: [
        {
          id: "",
          applicable_date: "",
          min_temp: "",
          max_temp: "",
          the_temp: "",
          wind_speed: "",
          weather_state_name: "",
          weather_state_abbr: "",
          wind_direction_compass: ""
        }
      ]
    };
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <section className="section-map">
          <div className="row home-row">
            <div className="col span-2-of-3">
              <EuropeMap cityCountry={this.state.cityCountry} />
            </div>

            <div className="col span-1-of-3">
              //{this.showWeatherDetailed(this.state.weather)}
            </div>
            <div>
              <h2>Coming data</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

Below code, is the methods in EuropeMap that has to end up updating the cityCountry state in Home, to trigger the Home render() method, however it does not seem to work.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../css/index.css";
import FetchClass from './FetchClass';

class EuropeMap extends Component {
  state = {
    previousCountryStyle: "",
    currentCountryCode: "",
  };

  handleCountryClick = evt => {
    var countryCode = evt.target.id;
    this.findWoeidForCountry(countryCode);
    //FetchClass.fetchCitiesForClickedCountry({...this.state.countryObject});
    console.log(countryCode);

    if (this.state.previousCountryStyle === "") {
      this.setState({ currentCountryCode: countryCode });
      evt.target.style.fill = "#f96e10";
    } else {
      this.setState({ currentCountryCode: countryCode });
      this.setPreviousCountryToGrey(this.state.previousCountryStyle);
      evt.target.style.fill = "#f96e10";
    }
    this.setState({ previousCountryStyle: evt.target.style });
  };
  setPreviousCountryToGrey = st => {
    st.fill = "#c0c0c0";
  };

  findWoeidForCountry = async countryCode => {

    const woeid = require("woeid");
    console.log(woeid.getWoeid(countryCode));
    if (countryCode !== "svg2") {
      const woeid2 = woeid.getWoeid(countryCode);
      const result = await FetchClass.fetchCitiesForClickedCountry(woeid2.woeid);
      this.setState({cityCountry: result})
      console.log("BYER: ", result);
      console.log(woeid2.woeid, 'Europe Map Find Woeid Method');
    }
  };
```

Can anybody please tell me, how I can parse a state variable to another component, so that I from component B can update the state in component A?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create method in the home component

```
updateCityCountry = val => this.setState({ cityCountry: val })
```

and instead of rendering the component as

```
<EuropeMap cityCountry={this.state.cityCountry} />
```

render as

```
<EuropeMap cityCountry={this.state.cityCountry} updateCity={this.updateCityCountry} />
```

and in the Europe Map component you can call

```
this.props.updateCity(result)
```

and this will be updated in the home component

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in your `Home` component that updates the `cityCountry` state variable and forward it to the `EuropeMap` component as a prop:

```
// in `Home`
updateCountry = (cityCountry) => this.setState({ cityCountry });

<EuropeMap updateCountry={this.updateCountry} { ... } />

// in `EuropeMap`
onSomethingHappend = () => {
    var data = somehowGetData();
    this.props.updateCountry(data);
}
```